# Is guarana more potent than ordinary coffee?

Tags: caffeine, fatigue, stimulants

As my fatigue increases, I am looking into natural stimulants.

In particular [guarana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guarana) caught my eye.

I never tried it so far. Is guarana more potent in preventing/alleviating fatigue than coffee?

Comment: It is against SE policy to give just mere opinions, so I've edited your question to make it a bit more on-topic (you can always roll-back to the previous version if you disagree). To get a more precise answer it would be useful if you described how you intend to use guarana and what type and amount of coffee are we comparing it to. Thanks!